# PDF bookmarks names for the appendices

Tags: appendices

This simple MWE gives me the desired outcome in the **text** of the PDF. However, when I open PDF, the **bookmarks** are called "Appendix" and "Appendix" instead of "Appendix A" and "Appendix B". Is there a simple and elegant way to fix that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[colorlinks, pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.25},bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=\maxdimen, citecolor={blue},urlcolor={blue}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Text (see \hyperref[Appendix A]{Appendix A} and \hyperref[Appendix B]{Appendix B})
\bigskip

\begin{appendices}

\section{}\label{Appendix A}
text

\section{}\label{Appendix B}
text

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

PDF text:

[image]

PDF bookmarks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[colorlinks, pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.25},bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=\maxdimen, citecolor={blue},urlcolor={blue}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Text (see \hyperref[Appendix A]{Appendix A} and \hyperref[Appendix B]{Appendix B})
\bigskip

\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}
\begin{appendices}

\section{}\label{Appendix A}
text

\section{}\label{Appendix B}
text

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Simple and elegant indeed!